# Options for converting 0 values to empty ("") cell by formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have quite long formula. I would like to hide zero values. Format cells is not an option as I am already using Format cells for separating 1000 (7000 -> 7 000). I would like to make zero values "". Is there any other shorter way to make them "", than using IF formula. Problem with IF formula is that it makes my formulas very long.

So if I have formula like:

```
 =IFERROR(IF(D34="";"";IF(D38="";0;(D36*D37*D38+D41*D38)*$B38)+IF(D39="";0;(D36*D37*D39+D41*D39)*$B39)+IF(D40="";0;(D36*D37*D40+D41*D40)*$B40)+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$38*D38*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$39*D39*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$40*D40*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+((D38+D39+D40)*D46*E46)+((D38+D39+D40)*D47*E47)+((D38+D39+D40)*D48*E48)+(D49*E49)+(D50*E50)+(E51/(1-E52)));"")
```

Then for IF returning "" it would be almost double the size:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D34="";"";IF(IF(D38="";0;(D36*D37*D38+D41*D38)*$B38)+IF(D39="";0;(D36*D37*D39+D41*D39)*$B39)+IF(D40="";0;(D36*D37*D40+D41*D40)*$B40)+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$38*D38*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$39*D39*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$40*D40*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+((D38+D39+D40)*D46*E46)+((D38+D39+D40)*D47*E47)+((D38+D39+D40)*D48*E48)+(D49*E49)+(D50*E50)+(E51/(1-E52))=0;"";IF(D38="";0;(D36*D37*D38+D41*D38)*$B38)+IF(D39="";0;(D36*D37*D39+D41*D39)*$B39)+IF(D40="";0;(D36*D37*D40+D41*D40)*$B40)+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$38*D38*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$39*D39*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+(SUM(D42:D45)*$B$40*D40*(1+'Other Data'!$C$35))+((D38+D39+D40)*D46*E46)+((D38+D39+D40)*D47*E47)+((D38+D39+D40)*D48*E48)+(D49*E49)+(D50*E50)+(E51/(1-E52))));"")
```

Comment: What are you using for your custom format?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld just number and "Use 1000 Separator ()"

Comment: then use something like `# ##0;-# ##0;""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to try:

Deselect the option to show zero's in the Advanced Options settings *(note that this is worksheet specific)*

[image: Format Cells]

Use the custom format:

```
# ##0.00_);(# ##0.00);
```

Note the semicolon at the very end

Comment: Conditional formatting would be a third rather easy one if you need some control on the range to apply it on (white fill or white font) but agreed with your first option as it is the cleanest way.

Comment: @JvdV The custom number format can also be range specific.  I didn't mention conditional formatting as another had already posted that.

Comment: I know, I just mentioned it as a third option to complete the answer nicely :)

Comment: I see Excel options way as a not so good solution, because on different computers it will work different way according to users preferences.

Comment: @user7202022 My preference would be the custom number format.  As to the Excel options, whether or not that is a good idea depends on whether that option follows the worksheet, or is specific to the computer being used, and whether or not the worksheet is going to be distributed if the option is computer specific. I don't know if that option follows the worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide zeroes with conditional formatting

```
=AND(A1=0;A1<>"")
```

And set characters text to white

oR USE `SumIFS` or set from Excel options